# Parallel execution with Jbehave with pico (jbehave-pico)

Tags: jbehave, picocontainer

I'm new Jbehave. Im trying to find a way to achieve world in cucumber with Jbehave. 
I generated project with jbehave with pico archetype. Im trying to run two stories in parallel. I updated threads in pom.xml to 2.
Consider a sample stepdef class as below

```
public class PojoSteps {

    public Pojo pojo;

    public PojoSteps(Pojo pojo){
        this.pojo = pojo;
        System.out.println(" @@" + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) + " * this is " + this + ". In PojoSteps constructor. Pojo created is:" + this.pojo + ". Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    @Given("I have a pojo with $i")
    public void iHaveAPojoWith1(int i){
        pojo.setI(i);
        System.out.println(" @@" + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) + " * this is " + this + ".In iHaveAPojoWith1. pojo = " + this.pojo +". Value of To be set = " + i +". Value set Pojo.getI() = " + this.pojo.getI() + ". Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    @When("I wait for some time")
    public void randomWait() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(200));
    }

    @Then("my pojo should still have $expectedi")
    public void myPojoShouldStillHave1(int expectedi){
        System.out.println(" @@" + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) + " * this is " + this +". In myPojoShouldStillHave1. pojo = " + this.pojo + ". expected = " + expectedi + ". actual = " + this.pojo.getI() + ". Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        Assert.assertEquals(this.pojo.getI(), expectedi);
    }
}
```

I have Pojo model as below

```
  public class Pojo {

    private int i;

    public void setI(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int getI(){
        return this.i;
    }
}
```

My two stories are as below
PojoOne.story

```
    Scenario: scenario description
       Given I have a pojo with 1
       When I wait for some time
       Then my pojo should still have 1
```

PojoTwo.story

```
 Scenario: random description
     Given I have a pojo with 2
     When I wait for some time
     Then my pojo should still have 2
```

I have MyStories class which extends JUnitStories as below

```
public class MyStories extends JUnitStories {
   ....
       private PicoContainer createPicoContainer() {
        MutablePicoContainer container = new DefaultPicoContainer(new Caching().wrap(new ConstructorInjection()));
        container.addComponent(PojoSteps.class);
        container.addComponent(Pojo.class);
        return container;
    }
 }
```

When I don't run stories in parallel, they succeed. When I run stories in parallel, they are failing.

```
 @@2020-01-02 20:35:36.53 * this is learning.steps.PojoSteps@49f3f232. In PojoSteps constructor. Pojo created is:learning.Support.Pojo@4aa9e824. Thread = 12
 @@2020-01-02 20:35:36.531 * this is learning.steps.PojoSteps@49f3f232.In iHaveAPojoWith1. pojo = learning.Support.Pojo@4aa9e824. Value of To be set = 1. Value set Pojo.getI() = 1. Thread = 12
 @@2020-01-02 20:35:36.532 * this is learning.steps.PojoSteps@6136e035. In PojoSteps constructor. Pojo created is:learning.Support.Pojo@1f4412c8. Thread = 13
 @@2020-01-02 20:35:36.533 * this is learning.steps.PojoSteps@6136e035.In iHaveAPojoWith1. pojo = learning.Support.Pojo@1f4412c8. Value of To be set = 2. Value set Pojo.getI() = 2. Thread = 13
 @@2020-01-02 20:35:36.558 * this is learning.steps.PojoSteps@6136e035. In myPojoShouldStillHave1. pojo = learning.Support.Pojo@1f4412c8. expected = 1. actual = 2. Thread = 12
 @@2020-01-02 20:35:36.668 * this is learning.steps.PojoSteps@6136e035. In myPojoShouldStillHave1. pojo = learning.Support.Pojo@1f4412c8. expected = 2. actual = 2. Thread = 13
...

Then my pojo should still have 1 (FAILED)
(java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<2> but was:<1>)
```

I'm not able to find documentation on how to run tests in parallel with Jbehave and pico. Also I need to have a model outside my stepdef class as I will be having multiple stefdef classes which will share the same model instance.

Comment: The issue is not in JBehave, but in the way how Pojo is managed. I'm not an expert in Pico, but I believe object of Pojo class is a singleton, thus it's state is shared across all threads: when one thread changes the value, it's properly updated for all other threads

Comment: true!! As stepdef instances are created only once, Pojo object is being overridden for multiple threads. Im struggling to find how to get this working with Jbehave - or what is suggested approach. Im trying to find how to share objects between stepsdef - including parallel execution.

Comment: you might need to try "Thread Caching": http://picocontainer.com/caching.html

Answer (score 0):

After reading a bit more and trying out Jbehave with spring, 
 1. I think there is no way to get different instances of stepdef created per thread. 
 2. In Jbehave, there is no equivalent of cucumber's `world` object which is threadsafe.

As @VaL mentioned in the comments of the questions, we have to make thinks threadsafe explicitly.

This is my understanding as of now. If there is any better way - kindly let me know.